# Proving the convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am attempting to prove if the below expression converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^2}$$

I decided to try using the [limit convergence test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx). So then, I set $f(n) = \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^2}$ and $g(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ and did the following:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-\frac{\ln(n) + 2}{n^2 (\ln n)^3}}{-\frac{1}{n^2}} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n) + 2}{n^2 (\ln n)^3} \cdot n^2 = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(\ln n)^2} + \frac{2}{(\ln n)^3} = 0
$$

I know that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges due to properties of harmonic series, and so concluded that my first expression $\frac{1}{n (\ln n)^2}$ also must diverge.

However, according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://bit.ly/WmGXQo), and as suggested by [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n-logs-n), the expression actually converges.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can use Cauchy's condensation test.

Comment: Your $f(x),g(x)$ do not depend on $x$, hence $f'(x)=g'(x)=0$. But you derive them $dn$, where $n$ is discrete. You should take much more care when doing things like that.

Comment: The integral test works well too.

Comment: is it $\log(x^2)$ or $(\log x)^2$?

Comment: @F'OlaYinka -- the latter

Comment: then it should have been written as $(\ln n)^2$ or $\ln^2n$, not $\ln(n)^2$. by putting brackets around $n$, it seems the "square" only applies to it.

Comment: Ok, I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: Note that, as R.J. Mathar posted in his not-an-answer answer, «The numerical constant and further literature are in http://oeis.org/A115563 .».

Comment: how do I find an integer such that $$\left\lvert s-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\;(ln\;n)^2}\right\rvert < 10^{-3}.$$ where  $s=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\;(ln\;n)^2}$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the limit comparison test, $\sum_n f(n)$ and $\sum_n g(n)$ both will behave the same iff
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = c \in (0,\infty)$$
In your case, the limit is $0$ and hence you cannot conclude anything.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [integral test for convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). Since the integral $$\int_2^\infty\dfrac{1}{x\log^2 x}dx$$ converges, the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^2}}$ converges.

Comment: Thank you -- this is what I ended up using, but I decided to accept Marvis's answer because it helped show me why the limit test wasn't working here.

Comment: The integral converges to 2, but is it correct to say that the series also converges to 2, or can we not make that conclusion?

Comment: @anna_xox I found that it converges to $\frac{1}{ln(2)}$ - did I calculate wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on the accepted answer, you should use the [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test): For a positive non-increasing sequence $f(n)$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)$ converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^nf(2^n)$ does.
In your case, $f(n)=\frac{1}{n\ln^2n}$, so 
$$2^nf(2^n)=2^n\frac{1}{2^n\ln^22^n}=\frac{1}{n^2\ln^22}=\frac{1}{\ln^22}\frac{1}{n^2}$$
which clearly converges.