# Series convergence help

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

If I have an increasing sequence of integers $$a_n$$ and $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(a_n)}{a_n}$$
diverges, does $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}$$ also diverge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counter example, consider $$a_{n-1} = n \ln^2(n)$$
Note that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{a_n}$ converges from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n-logs-n). 
Whereas $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\ln(a_n)}{a_n} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{\ln(n \ln^2(n))}{n \ln^2(n)} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{\ln(n)+ \ln( \ln^2(n))}{n \ln^2(n)} = \underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n \ln (n)}}_{\text{Diverges}} + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{\ln( \ln^2(n))}{n \ln^2(n)}$$

Comment: +1 It is a magic sequence $a_n$. I was searching in my old examples but didn't find such this key-like sequence.

Comment: @BabakSorouh Yes. I too feel the sequence $a_n = \dfrac1{n \log^2(n)}$ is a nice sequence and can help us to analyze/ get an idea for slightly non-trivial convergence/divergence.