# Does the series converge or diverge? (just need a way to approach the problem - no answer please)

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln(2n)}}$$

To I am trying to figure out exactly what to compare this series to in order to prove that it diverges. I know that $1/n$ diverges and I also know that by the p-series the square root diverges as well. Can anybody give me a good way to approach this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Compare with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n \ln(n)}$ and conclude from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n-logs-n).

Comment: How can you compare that sum when at 1 the sum is undefined?

Comment: @JohnCarpenter Ok. Start from $2$.

Comment: Ok so how can you compare two sums that have diff starting points?

Comment: @JohnCarpenter Write your series as the first term + the terms starting from $n=2$. And note that it converges/diverges only when the series from $n=2$ converges/diverges respectively.

Comment: Ah thanks you sir.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter:  The important point is that convergence only depends on what happens "at infinity".  Anything that happens "down low" can change the limit, but can't change whether the series converges, so can be ignored.  A few extra terms, some (finite) number of terms altered, etc, don't change whether the series converges.