# Absolute Convergence of a Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-value

Find all values of real number *p* for which the series converges absolutely

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{k\, (\log{k})^p}$$

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know Cauchy's condensation test? Do you know the Integral test?

Comment: My book hasn't said anything about Cauchy's condensation test yet. I've tried just placing different general values in for p (p = 0, p >0, p < 0). I can see why p = 0 would not work, but I am having trouble seeing why it doesn't converge when p < 0 (according to the back of the book.) And I was thinking the if p > 0 it would converge because it would be similar to a p-series. I still don't quite understand the integral test.

Comment: It is good your write that **everytime** you ask this kind of questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of the series $\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\log^s n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-logs-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
Try by using [Integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)

Comment: i had to remember how to take those kind of integrals. thank you

Answer (score 4):

This is amenable to the well-known [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) that goes as follows:

If we have a non-negative decreasing sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1,2,\ldots}^{\infty}$, then
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n \text{ converges iff }\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} 2^na_{2^n} \text{ converges}$$

In your case, we have $a_n = \dfrac1{n \log^p(n)}$.

> Hence,$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} 2^na_{2^n} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}  \dfrac{2^n}{2^n (n \log2)^p} = \dfrac1{(\log2)^p}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}  \dfrac1{n^p}$$ which converges for $p>1$ and diverges for $p \leq 1$.

Comment: I wish this was in my book. That seems so much more simple.