# An Integral Designed to be on the Very Cusp of Convergence

Tags: integration, limits, tetration

Say we have an integer $n$∊ℕ₀ & a sequence of $n+1$ real numbers $\alpha_k\in[0,\infty)∀k$, where $k=0\dots n$, and using $\log^{[k]}$ to denote $k$ *functionings* of the logarithm ($\log^{[0]}x\equiv x$, $\log^{[1]}x\equiv \log x$,  $\log^{[2]}x\equiv \log\log x$, etc), I would conjecture that, $∀n, $ the integral $$\int_{e\uparrow\uparrow n}^\infty{dx\over\prod_{k=0}^n(\log^{[k]}x)^{\alpha_k}}$$ *diverges*, when $\alpha_k=1∀k\leq n$, or when *with ascending* $k$ the first $\alpha_k≠1$ is $<1$; and *converges* when *with ascending* $k$ the first $\alpha_k≠1$ is $>1$.

In the integral given the lower limit is chosen simply to keep the function in the denominator well clear of taking any argument that would result in a negative value being fed into the logarithm - the convergence|divergence of the integral is determined purely by the behaviour of the integrand as its argument $\to\infty$.

I am wondering whether this surmise is correct. My reasoning for supposing it is is that if the variable $y$ be substituted for $\log^{[n]}x$, then in the denominator we shall have successive orders of *functioning* of the *exponential* of $y$ from right to left ... but each raised to the power of its index $\alpha_k$ in order from left to right; and in the numerator we shall have the same product of the same factors, by reason of the chain rule, but each with *unit* exponent. So that considering the factors from left to right, the first one that does not *completely* cancel will be the first one at which $\alpha_k$ differs from unity; and also the one with the highest order of application of the exponential function: and if that $a_k$ is $<1$ the remnant will be in the numerator, and if $>1$, in the denominator. And the integral will diverge in the former case & converge in the latter, as subsequent remnants will be completely overruled, regardless of the size of their exponent, as an *exponential* of a variable *always* overrules a mere *power* of a variable, regardless of the relative sizes of the scaling of the exponential and the degree of the power ... and the comparison will be *at least that*. Finally, in the case of all the $\alpha_k$ till the last being $=1$, there will be *complete* cancellation of the exponentials; and we shall be left with $$\int_{e\uparrow\uparrow n}^\infty{dy\over y^{\alpha_n}} ,$$ the convergence|divergence of which depends on $\alpha_n$ in the well-familiar way.

I would also surmise that this theorem - if it indeed *is* one (and the question here is essentially *whether* it *is* one, and not merely a surmise, or incorrectly infererred) - translates into sum over integers. I'll refrain from fully explicating the logic of that surmise; but basically it's that if the correspondence between Σ & ∫ of $1/x$ holds by reason of the *asymptotically-flat* -ness of the logarithm, then it could reasonably be expected to hold when functions that are progressively yet asymptotically-flatter are factored-in.

Comment: For clarification, is the theorem just showing how this integral ($n$ fixed) switches from divergent to convergent as one of the exponents changes -- or are you asserting that there is such a thing as an integral on "the very cusp of convergence"?

Comment: @RRL -- The thought behind it is ... we know that 1/x is divergent, but if we have 1/x^(1+ε) it becomes _convergent_, howsoever small ε might be ... so what else _can_ we freight the denominator with & it still be divergent ... let's try a _logarithm_, as it increases slower than any power of x ... yes! it's _still_ divergent ... _but_ if we put a further (log)^ε on, no matter how small ε, it becomes _convergent_ ... but could there possibly be _just a tiny little bit more_ thst we could freight the denominator with and it still be divergent ... I know! let's try loglog(x) ...

Comment: @RRL -- yes! it's still divergent! But if we put on even so much as a (loglog(x))^ε, no matter how small ε .... & so on & so on ... ¶ The idea came from noting how the sum of reciprocals is divergent; and then that the sum of reciprocals of _primes only_ is _still_ divergent and that's asymptotically equivalent to summing 1/x.logx, as primes of size x are on average logx apart ... but then! ... you get Brun's constant - the sum of _twin_ primes, which is _convergent_ & that is asymptotically sum of 1/x(logx)^2 ... so all this got me wondering just where _exactly_ the cusp _is_ tween con & div.

Comment: @RRL -- SO I'm saying it looks to me like the cusp is at $$1/\prod_{k=0}^\infty\log^{[k]}(x) ;$$ and that if the exponent of _any_ of those factors depart by the _tiniest amount_ from unity it _absolutely settles_ it one way or the other, _utterly regardless_ of what any subsequent exponent might be. And I haven't found any explicit statement of what I have said here in _any_ text or paper ... so I'm 'farming it out' here for confirmation ... or refutal, as the case may be!

Comment: I think everything you say and prove here about the nature of this integral is correct (+1). My only concern is the meaning of "very cusp of convergence."

Comment: @RRL -- Might be a tad _poetic_, I suppose; but I think I have quite thoroughly defined what I mean by it: the way it's _absolutely_ sensitive to the sequence of exponents; and that as far as I can see you could not freight the denominator _any more __atall___ & it still be divergent.

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation of on "the very cusp of convergence" is a function with a divergent integral such that **any** asymptotically smaller function has a   convergent integral.

To argue there can be no integral on the very cusp of convergence in this sense, consider a positive function $f : [1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^+$ where $\int_1^\infty f(x) \, dx = +\infty$.

Taking $g(x) = \int_1^x f(t) \, dt$, we have for $\beta > \alpha > 1$,

$$\left|\int_{\alpha}^\beta \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \, dx \right| \geqslant \frac{1}{g(\beta)}\int_{\alpha}^\beta f(x) \, dx = \frac{g(\beta)- g(\alpha)}{g(\beta)} = 1 - \frac{g(\alpha)}{g(\beta)}$$

Since $g(\alpha)/g(\beta) \to 0$ as $\beta \to +\infty$ with $\alpha$ fixed, there exists for any $\alpha$, no matter how large, a $\beta $ such that the RHS is greater than $1/2$. Since the Cauchy criterion is violated and the integrand is positive, we have

$$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \, dx = + \infty$$

However, since $g(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$ we have $f(x) \geqslant \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ for all sufficiently large $x$.

Hence, given a divergent integral there always is another  divergent integral with an asymptotically subordinate integrand.

Comment: Are you saying it's sort of like an _open set_ ... similar to the way you can't exhibit the least element in (0,1]?

Comment: Yes -- this  notion of "no slowest" divergent series and improper integral is discussed in various places -- for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/588488/148510).

Comment: So no matter how close a function might be to this 'cusp', as I call, it, that function _divided by its own integral_ will still be divergent!?

Comment: Well! It's certainly _extremely_ interesting this business of there being no 'least divergent' sum or integral! Looks like _refutal_ afterall then! I am surprised, TBPH ... and I can't imagine _what in the world_ increasing-to-∞ function you could put in the denominator of my function & it still be divergent! Well ... as you've pointed out - it's _own integral_! But ... isn't that kind of what it is, sort of: the limit to infinity of doing _precisely that_?

Comment: I'm actually genuinely grateful for this contribution & very much appreciate it. One ought not to become too fond of one's own results afterall; unless perhaps they be _ironcladly proven_! ¶ In your first paragraph I think you've put 'convergent' where you mean _di_ -vergent. It doesn't throw me _atall_, as I get what you're saying ... but someone else might be abitt.

Comment: Thanks -- see if my edit fixes the language.

Comment: So $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges but so does $\sum \frac{1}{n \log n}$ and so does $\sum \frac{1}{n \log n \log \log n}$ and so on.  More generally if $\sum a_n$ diverges(with $a_n > 0$) then so must $\displaystyle \sum \frac{a_n}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}$

Comment: Ah yes! That would be the _sum_ equivalent of the _integral_ you showed in your answer (answer _as such_ ... not just _comment_).

Comment: & also you could do a limit of such sums nested in a similar manner to how that in which I formulated my infinite product. $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n1/\bigg)^m1 ,$$maybe ... something like that! ¶ No it's not exactly that ... how would you do it _slickly_? Rhetorical question! - unless you genuinely _fancy_ doing it ... I have no choice - I shan't be able to leave it till I've sorted it now!

Comment: Also, IIRC, for every convergent series, there exists a series with asymptotically larger terms which also converges.  (I think I also remember seeing these facts as exercises in functional analysis, under the Open Mapping Theorem / Closed Graph Theorem section.)

Comment: I don't think you can really ... you just have to define the terms of the next order in terms of those of the present one, & say "the limit of _that_". I think you do anyway ... but I'm leaving it now ... I think I might be _on the very cusp_ of very _paroxysms_!