# $\sum_n a_n < \infty \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \phi(n)a_n = \text{const.}$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, summation

I'm wondering how the following statement can be disproved.

Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence and assume there exists a function $\phi(n)$ with the properties
$$\sum_n a_n < \infty \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \phi(n)a_n = \text{const.} \, .$$
I want to show, no such function can exist.

This question is along the lines of the answer given by Winther: [If $\sum_{n_0}^{\infty} a_n$ diverges prove that $\sum_{n_0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_1+a_2+...+a_n} = +\infty $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135536/if-sum-n-0-infty-a-n-diverges-prove-that-sum-n-0-infty-fraca-n/1606708#1606708). He gives a proof for the case, where the constant is $0$. I'm wondering if the positive constant case makes a difference.

Just a few observations:

1. $\phi(n)$ clearly must be asymptotically increasing, as $a_n$ is a null-sequence.
2. The sequence $$a_n=\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x} \left(\log(\log(...\log(x)))\right)^s \Bigg|_{x=n} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x} \left(\log^{(m)}(x)\right)^s \Bigg|_{x=n} = \frac{s}{n\left(\log^{(m)}(n)\right)^{1-s}} \left(\prod_{k=1}^{m-1} \log^{(k)}(n) \right)^{-1}$$
   converges (by the integral criterion) for $s<0$ and diverges if $s>0$, where $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Because of this, if such a function existed, it would formally have the form $$\phi(n) \simeq n \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \log^{(k)}(n) \, , \tag{1}$$
   not worrying about convergence of the product or if it is defined otherwise.
3. The difference to Abel's proof is, that the sum $$\sum_n \frac{1}{\phi(n)}$$ would actually converge, because $\phi(n) \frac{1}{\phi(n)}=1$, not leading to the desired contradiction as in Abel's proof. Whether the sum, with $\phi(n)$ as in (1), would formally converge or not... I wouldn't know how to make sense of it.

Comment: Your statement is a bit unclear. What statement are you trying to disprove? The statement that follows your request to to help you disprove it is an imperative statement, which takes no truth value. Please clarify what you are trying to disprove. Because at the moment, what you have written contains no declarative statement whose truth value is in question.

Comment: The good question would be: is there a convergent series such that $\lim_n\phi(n)a_n$ is finite but nonzero. The generalized Bertrand series suggest that it's difficult. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/588527/43608) means it's not possible. The problem is, for any convergent series such that $\lim_n\phi(n)a_n=L>0$, we can find a convergent series that converges slower, in the sense that $\lim_n\phi(n)a_n=+\infty$. Therefore the limit has to always be zero, and the original post is already the fully general answer.

Comment: Also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/452074/42969

Comment: Because of the order in which you are declaring $a_n$ and $\phi$, the obvious question is, does $\phi$ depend on $a_n$? Again, you are declaring its existence in an imperative statement (or the assumption of its existence). Suppose $a_n$ is convergent and declare $\phi(n)=\dfrac{L}{a_n}$ but if it is divergent, declare $$\phi(n)=\begin{cases}\tfrac{1}{a_n} & n\equiv 0 \pmod{2} \\ 0 & n\equiv 1 \pmod{2}\end{cases}$$ trivially satisfies the conditions for the chosen $a_n$. For the answers given above, you must choose your function before choosing your sequence.

Comment: @Slip: I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to explain. Clearly $\phi(n)$ does not depend on a specific $a_n$, but only on the fact whether a sum associated to $a_n$ is convergent/divergent.

Comment: @Diger I clearly did not find your question clear. It was not until others answered that I understood what you were asking. I hoped that by pointing out the ambiguity of your question, you might update it so that it is more clear for other readers. Or at least try to make your future questions more precise. Obviously, you got your answer for this question.

Comment: If you want me to clear up the question a little bit, where specifically would you do it? I'm not sure where exactly it is still unclear. Thanks to @Jean-Claude Arbaut for your insightful comment. I think everything is clear now. Btw: you posted an answer and deleted it, why?

Comment: @Diger Because I wanted first to find a good reference for the much stronger theorem that I use in the answer (undeleted now). This question is very interesting from a historical point of view: the condition $\phi(n)a_n\to0$ was an attempt to replace the wrong condition $na_n\to0$, but all of this was settled with the more general theorem (and the generalized Bertrand series gives an infinite sequence of slower and slower converging series (and conversely slower and slower diverging series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(thanks to Martin R for pointing to an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452053/is-there-a-slowest-rate-of-divergence-of-a-series/452074#452074) that gives a proof and a reference for the theorem used below)*

The question you point to explains that this is related to the historical search for a function $\phi$ such that a series with positive terms $a_n$ is convergent iff $\lim_n\phi(n)a_n=0$. Both this case and your attempt to relax the condition to $\lim_n\phi(n)a_n=L<\infty$ can be dealt with thanks to the following theorem, proved for instance in [1]:

> **Theorem**
>
> Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ be any convergent series with positive terms. Then there exists a convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ with much bigger terms in the sense that
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{C_n}{c_n}=\infty$$
>
> Similarly, for any divergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty D_n$ with positive terms, there exists a divergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty d_n$ with much smaller terms in the sens that
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{d_n}{D_n}=0$$

Assume that such a $\phi$ exists, with your relaxed condition. Then assuming there exists a convergent series for which $\lim_n \phi(n)a_n=L>0$, we can find a convergent series with terms $A_n$, such that $\frac{A_n}{a_n}\to\infty$. Therefore, $\lim_n \phi(n)A_n=\lim_n (\phi(n)a_n)\frac{A_n}{a_n}=\infty$, which is impossible since we are supposed to have $\lim_n \phi(n)A_n=L'<\infty$. So, the limit $L$ has to be zero, for all convergent series.

But even then, it won't work. First note that WLOG we can replace $\phi$ with $|\phi|$, so we can assume $\phi$ is positive. Consider the series with positive terms $D_n=\frac{1}{\phi(n)}$. Since $\phi(n)D_n\to1$, the series is divergent. Therefore, we can find another divergent series with positive terms $d_n$, such that $\frac{d_n}{D_n}\to0$. But then $\lim_n\phi(n)d_n=\lim_n(\phi(n)D_n)\frac{d_n}{D_n}=0$, which contradicts the fact that the series is divergent.

Therefore, such a $\phi$ can't exist.

Note that such a $\phi$ is akin to a fixed boundary between convergent and divergent series, and what the theoreom above say is such a boundary doesn't exist.

---

[1] J. Marshall Ash ,"Neither a Worst Convergent Series nor a Best Divergent Series Exists", [The College Mathematics Journal](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal)
Vol. 28, No. 4 (Sep., 1997), pp. 296-297,
JSTOR [2687153](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2687153), DOI [10.2307/2687153](https://doi.org/10.2307/2687153)

Comment: I think that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452053/is-there-a-slowest-rate-of-divergence-of-a-series/452074#452074 is a pretty good reference on mse as well (summing up the paper). Short and succinct.

Comment: @Diger True. And it points to the same article. But Martin R found this question after I wrote the comment above, and only then I had what I was looking for ;) I added credits in the answer.