# Show that the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\, (\log n)^s}$ converges for $s >1$ and diverges for $s=1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the series

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\, (\log n)^s}$$
converges for $s >1$ and diverges for $s=1$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-logs-n