# Series; Dyadic Test

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the range of p for which the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^p}$ is convergent. I want to use dyadic test rather than integral test. Anyone can help?

Comment: Anyone know how to make the LaTex code work? This is my first time using it here.

Comment: Put $$ around it.

Comment: I edited post, please check formula

Comment: What's *dyadic test*, I can't google & find it.

Comment: Thank you! Dyadic Test: Suppose $(a_n)$ is a non-increasing sequence and $a_n \ge 0$, then $\sum a_k$ converges if and only if $\sum 2^k\times a_{2^k}$ converges.

Comment: What Steve calls "dyadic test" is what is also known, perhaps more commonly, as (Cauchy's) Condensation Test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of the series $\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\log^s n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-logs-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Cauchy Condensation Test,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) which is probably what you mean by a dyadic test, a decreasing series of positive terms $\sum_{n=2}^\infty f(n)$ converges if and only if
$\sum_{k=2}^\infty 2^k f(2^k)$ converges.

In our case, $f(n)=\frac{1}{n(\ln n)^p}$, and therefore 
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty 2^k f(2^k)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln 2)^pk^p}.$$
Now we can use the fact that $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{k^p}$ converges if and only if $p\gt 1$.

**Remark:** If you want to prove that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^p}$ converges iff $p\gt 1$, you can use Cauchy Condensation once more. One ends up with a geometric series.

Comment: You are welcome.