# Theorem 3.29 in Baby Rudin

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Theorem 3.29 in Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, 3rd ed., states that

> If $p>1$, then the series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n (\log n)^p} $$ converges; if $p \leq 1$, the series diverges.

Now in the proof, Rudin only seems to discuss the case when $p> 0$, for it is only in this particular case that we can use the Cauchy Condensation Test.

How to deal with the case of $p<0$?

Of course, the case $p=0$ yields the divergent harmonic series.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-logs-n

Comment: Rudin relates this to theorem 3.28 ($\sum \frac{1}{n^p} $ converges if $p \gt 1$ and diverges, if $p \leq 1$). This was proved for all $p$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The case of $p<0$ is trivial, since 
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\ln^{-p} k}{k}\ge\sum_{k=4}^\infty \frac{1}{k}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the integral test:

$$ \sum_{n \geq 2 }\frac{1}{n ( \log n )^p} \cong \int\limits_2^{\infty} \frac{dz}{z (\log z )^p} = \int\limits_{2}^{\infty} \frac{ d(\log z)}{ ( \log z )^p }= ...$$

Comment: The integral test is not to be used; I'd like to do a a theorem in Rudin and so use the same armory that he's given me uptil this point.