# For what values of $p$ does $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k\log^p(k+1)}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find all $p\geq 0$ such that the following series converges $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k\log^p(k+1)}$.

Proof: the general term for the series is $\frac{k^p}{k^p\log^p(k+1)^n} = \frac{1}{k\log^p(k+1)^n}$.

By comparison, $\frac{1}{\log^pn}\leq \frac{1}{\log^p(n+1)}
$.
And it's convergent when $p>1$ thus $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k\log^p(k+1)}$ is convergent when $p>1$ and divergent when $0 < p < 1$.

Can anyone please verify this?
Any suggestion would help. I was trying to use the integral test, but I don't know how to do it.
Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but hardly anything you've written here makes any sense.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Try the integral test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of the series $\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\log^s n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-logs-n)

Answer (score 3):

Recall that, by the integral test, for a monotonically decreasing non-negative function $f$, you have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty f(x)dx\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)\leq f(1)+\int_1^\infty f(x)dx.
\end{align}
$$ Here, if you put $\displaystyle x \mapsto f(x):=\frac{1}{x (\ln(x+1))^p}, \: p>0$, you get that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k) $ and $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx $ **either both converge or both diverge**.

1. Let $p$ be such that $p>1$.

   You may write $$
   \begin{align}
   &\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x (\ln(x+1))^p}\, dx\\\\
   &=\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x+1}{x}\frac{\frac{1}{(x+1)}}{(\ln(x+1))^p}\, dx\\\\
   &=\left.\frac{x+1}{x}\left(-\frac{1}{p-1}\frac{1}{(\ln(x+1))^{p-1}}\right)\right|_1^{\infty} -\frac{1}{p-1}\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{(\ln(x+1))^{p-1}} dx\\\\
   &=\frac{2}{(p-1) (\ln 2)^{p-1}} - \frac{1}{p-1}\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{(\ln(x+1))^{p-1}} dx
   \end{align}
   $$ the latter integral is convergent since, the potential problem being as $x \to +\infty$ and we have
   $$
   \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{(\ln(x+1))^{p-1}}  \leq \frac{1}{x^2}, \quad x\geq2, 
   $$ your series is thus **convergent** in this case.
2. Let $p$ be such that $0<p<1$.

   Since, for $x \to +\infty$, you have $$  \frac{1}{x
       (\ln(x+1))^p} \sim \frac{1}{x
       (\ln x)^p}$$ 
   then, for $M$ sufficiently great, you get
   $$ \int_M^{+\infty}\!\! \frac{1}{x
       (\ln(x+1))^p}\:dx \sim \int_M^{+\infty}\!\! \frac{1}{x
       (\ln x)^p} \:dx$$  the latter
   integral is divergent since $$  \int_M^{+\infty}\!\! \frac{1}{x
       (\ln x)^p} dx= \int_M^{+\infty}\!\! \frac{(\ln x)'}{(\ln x)^p}\:dx=\left.\frac{(\ln x)^{1-p}}{1-p}\right|_M^{+\infty}=+\infty$$ and your series is **divergent** in this case.

Answer (score 1):

By **Cauchy condensation test** all gets reduced to the study of 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^p}$$
whence we get the conclusions according to the values of $p$.

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f (k) = \frac{1}{k\log^p(k+1)}$. When $g (k) = 2^k f (2^k)$, we have $$\sum f (k) \leqslant \sum g (k) \leqslant 2 \sum f (k),$$ so if one converges, the other converges too. We have $$g (k) = \frac {1} {(k + 1)^{p \log 2}}.$$ Then $\sum g (k)$, so $\sum f (k)$ converges when $p > 1/\log 2$.