# find all real values of $x$ for which the series converges absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis

**The problem:**

> Find all  real values of $x$ for which the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n(\log n)^2}$$
>   converges absolutely.

**My attempt:** 
My answer is  $|x| <1$ because when $n \to \infty$,  $x^ n$  tends  to $0$  if  $-1<x<1$

Is it correct?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I guess the series is also absolutely convergent when $x=1$ or $x=-1$ because $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}$ is convergent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that's correct indeed by root test we obtain

$$|x|\left(\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}\right)^\frac1n\to |x|<1$$

and it converges also for $x=\pm 1$, can you see why?

Comment: if $x = -1$, then  it will converges by leibnitz test???? Am i right

Comment: @jasmine Once we know that it converges for $x=1$ it converges also absolutely for $x=-1$ therefore we don't need to invoke Leibnitz.

Comment: @ gimusi that mean  answer  will be $[-1,1]$?  Am i right ??

Comment: @jasmineYes of course. How do you prove convergence for the case $x=1$?

Comment: @ gimusii mean $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(logn)^2}  \le  \sum \frac{1}{n^2} $? we know  by  p- test  it will converge

Comment: @jasmine Mmmhhhh...that's does not seem a good method.You are claiming that the LHS is greater than something that converges, how can we conclude from here?

Comment: @ gimusi ,,,i gots  its  ..thanks  u

Comment: @jasmine We need integral test to prove that or Cauchy condensation test. Refer to the related [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2823441/505767)

Comment: @jasmine You are welcome! Be

Comment: $f(1)=2.10974280123689197448$ and $f(-1)=0.84776283970567945082$

Comment: @robjohn Thank! Are those numerical estimation?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! After you have pointed out my mistakes, I was searching for some related OP and I've found that. That's really a too advanced problem for my current knowledge :(

Comment: @gimusi: yes, they are not exact, but they are accurate to the precision given.

Comment: @robjohn Ah ok, I thought I was missing something else. Thank again! Bye