# Infinite Series Comparison Test

Tags: real-analysis

I have been trying to solve this problem for many hours, but I am lost. I would like to use the Comparison Test. However, any other test would be also OK.

I am interested not only in the exponent 0.5. I am interested in all the exponents that are elements of the interval (0,1).

log in the image is natural log.

I am posting "the solution" of WolframAlpha.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Is your question that you want a proof about the convergence or divergence of $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log^k(n+1)}$$ for all $k \in (0,1)$? In particular, a proof that uses the comparison test?

Comment: According to WolframAlpha the series diverges. I would prefer a proof that use the Comparison Test. But, any other test is also welcome.

Comment: I used the integral test for a similar series that inside the log has n instead of (n+1). That series diverges. However, I cannot use it for the Comparison Test because that series is greater that the one of the problem.

Comment: Compare with $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln n}$, this one you can use the integral test to show the divergence.

Comment: As the series is known to diverge, it suffices to show divergence for $k=1$ (the fastest decrease rate).

Comment: @FrankLu I checked and it is working! Great idea thank you so much!

Comment: @YvesDaoust Excellent comment! Thank you!

Comment: @FrankLu One question. What can I do if I need also 1 in the interval? For that point the series that you found does not work because the one of the problem is smaller, then I cannot apply the Comparison Test.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The series that Frank Lu suggested does not work for k=1. May you help me with one that works for k=1?

Comment: If starts at $k=1$ you can try $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln(n+1)}$. This one also works, but just need to be a little careful to make the argument rigorors. Essentially if you can prove that the tail of this series diverges, you are done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of the series $\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\log^s n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac1n-logs-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\alpha\in(0,1)$, note that 
$$\frac{1}{n\ln^\alpha (n+1)}>\frac{1}{n\ln (n+1)}=\frac{1}{n(\ln n+\ln\frac{n+1}{n})}>\frac{1}{2n\ln n},$$
whenever $n$ is sufficiently large, for example say $n>4$.
Then by integral test you can show that $\sum_{n=5}^\infty\frac{1}{2n\ln n}$ diverges. It follows that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln^\alpha(n+1)}\geq\sum_{n=1}^4\frac{1}{n\ln^\alpha(n+1)}+\sum_{n=5}^\infty\frac{1}{2n\ln n}=+\infty.$$

Comment: Amazing proof! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

By the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), this compares to the following sum:

$$2\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\ln^kn}\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n}{2^n\ln^k2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^k\ln^k2}=\frac1{\ln^k2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^k}$$

Again by the Cauchy condensation test, this compares to the following sum:

$$2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^k}\ge\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{(2^n)^k}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2^{1-k})^n$$

which is a geometric series and diverges when $k\le1$.

Comment: Fantastic proof! Thank you so much!

Comment: :D Your welcome!

Comment: It is more relevant to say that the series diverges when $k\le1$, isn't it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust oh, right lol.